# Retornar valores da Database

Tags: php, loop, memória

Estou obtendo este erro:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 1640 bytes) in C:\AppServ\www\muweb\class\Connect.php on line
>   31

Quando executo esses script:

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'settings/Config.php';
require_once 'class/Connect.php';
require_once 'class/Characters.php';


 $char = new Characters;


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SELECT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Conta ID</th>
                <th>Personagem</th>
                <th>Dinheiro</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            while ($get = $char->fetch()):
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $get['AccountID']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $get['Name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $get['Money']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Connect.php**

```
<?php

class Connect {

    private $_cn;
    private $_db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Connection();
        $this->Database();
    }

    private function Connection() {
        $this->_cn = mssql_connect(HOST, USER, PASS);

        if ($this->_cn == false) {
            die('Connection error!');
        }
    }

    private function Database() {
        $this->_db = mssql_select_db(BASE, $this->_cn);

        if ($this->_db == false) {
            die('Select database error!');
        }
    }

    public function execute($query) {

        $execute = mssql_query($query);

        if ($execute == false) {
            die('Execute error:' . $query);
        } else {
            return $execute;
        }
    }

    public function row($query) {
        return mssql_fetch_row($query);
    }

    public function fetch($query) {
        return mssql_fetch_array($query);
    }

    public function num($query) {
        return mssql_num_rows($query);
    }
}
```

**characters.php**

```
<?php

class Characters extends Connect {

    public function fetch() {
        $fetch = $this->fetch($this->execute("SELECT * FROM Character WHERE AccountID = 'guialves95'"));
        return $fetch;
    }

    public function num() {
        $num = $this->num($this->execute("SELECT * FROM Character WHERE AccountID = 'guialves95'"));

        return $num;
    }
}
```

Já fiz de tudo mas não consigo solucionar o problema, uma rápida pesquisa, alguns casos conseguiram solucionar adicionando está linha de código:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```

Comigo não deu certo, qual a solução para este problema?

Tenho comigo, que, meu `loop` está fora de controle.

Comment: Você está chamando a função ``fetch`` toda hora, troca o ``$this`` por ``parent``, era para chamar a da classe Connect certo?

Comment: @fernandoandrade não é necessário. Com mais tempo explico o por que.

Comment: Engano meu é necessario sim, desculpa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está a extender a Class Connect com Characters e a reescrever o método fetch. O fetch de Characters está a fazer override e assim o fetch de Connect nunca é utilizado.

O que está a acontecer é que o seu while() está a entrar em ciclo infinito com o fetch e só para quando ocupa a memória toda disponível.

**Solução**: Primeiro experimente mudar o nome da sua função fetch de Characters para outro nome. O mesmo acontece com a função num.

**[UPDATE]**

A função fetch_array deve ser usada dentro de uma query. Você está a usar fora.

Aqui fica uma solução:

```
//Connect.php
<?php
public function fetch($query) {
  $results = array();
  while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query))
  {
    $results[] = $row;
  }
  return $results;
}

//Characters.php
public function fetchCharacters() {
  $results = $this->fetch($this->execute("SELECT * FROM Character WHERE AccountID = 'guialves95'"));
}
?>
//Index.php
<?php
foreach ($char->fetchCharacters() as $char):
?>

<tr>
  <td><?php echo $char['AccountID']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $char['Name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $char['Money']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Vou rever esses conceitos e volto com notícias.

Comment: etNos, troquei o nome da função `fetch()` ele me retornou os valores, mas não todos que eu preciso, tenho 3 Characters na minha DB, e ele me retornou só 1 com loop infinito ainda. Veja a imagem http://i.imgur.com/m9zWd6g.png

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO fiz um update na resposta. Veja se assim funciona.

Comment: não funcionou,... :/

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() EDIT: Funcionou, tinha que retornar $results